# How to generate clipPath like the one in image provided

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, flutter, clip-path

I want to generate a widget which have the clippath like the one in the given image. I am talking about the white section of the app screen here, which contains information.

[image]

Below code was what I was trying while experimenting, but failed !

```
 Path getClip(Size size) {
var path = new Path();
var controlpoint = Offset(10.0, size.height);
var endpoint = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height);

path.lineTo(0.0, size.height - 100);

path.quadraticBezierTo(
    controlpoint.dx, controlpoint.dy, endpoint.dx, endpoint.dy);

path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
path.lineTo(size.width, 0.00);

return path;
```

Please help me with this code :)

Edit : I got till this part but I'm still stuck :(

```
**Path getClip(Size size) {
final path = Path();
path.lineTo(size.width, 100);
path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
path.lineTo(0.00, size.height);
path.close();

return path;
```

}**

and above custom clipPath, using ClipRRect.

[image]

Comment: check `Path#arcToPoint()` method

Comment: any link which i can refer ?

Comment: [arcToPoint](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/arcToPoint.html)

Comment: i am still loss here :(

Comment: i got the result for all the point except the starting one above nike. i get a pointed shape on top :(

Comment: @pskink can you help here ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally some playing with the code ended up with the following output:

```
Path getClip(Size size) {
final path = Path();
path.lineTo(20.0, 0.0);
path.lineTo(size.width, 120);
path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
path.lineTo(0.00, size.height);
path.close();

return path;
```

had added a parent is of some like this:

```
ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(25.0),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25.0),
          ),
          child: ClipPath(
          clipper: SinglePageClipper(),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 400,
                ),
                Center(child: Text('Demo Page'),)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

I think this is some thing which can be improved so will try to do so. but in the mean while if some one have a better approach. please enlighten us with the knowledge as this was way more time consuming for beginner like me.